# has anyone created an isotope dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-isotope

has anyone been able to create a dropdown menu bar in isotope? I have read some reference to it here but nothing that materialized. I found this example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trewknowledge/jJZEN/) although I am looking for five dropdown buttons across like [this](http://www.ekhartyoga.com/videos) that also would work with videos. Appreciate any help!

The HTML

```
<div id="filters">
    <select>
        <option value="*">All</option>
        <option value=".red">Red</option>
        <option value=".green">Green</option>
        <option value=".blue">Blue</option>
        <option value=".yellow">Yellow</option>        
    </select>    
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    var $container = $('#container'),
    $select = $('#filters select');

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });

    $select.change(function() {
        var filters = $(this).val();
        $container.isotope({
            filter: filters
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/jubmr

```
$( function() {
    // init Isotope
    var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });
    // filter functions
    var filterFns = {
    // show if number is greater than 50
    numberGreaterThan50: function() {
        var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
        return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
    },
    // show if name ends with -ium
    ium: function() {
        var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
        return name.match( /ium$/ );
    }
};

// bind filter on select change
$('#filters').on( 'change', function() {
        // get filter value from option value
        var filterValue = this.value;
        // use filterFn if matches value
        filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
        $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });
});
```

2: use html dropDown list

Comment: Thank you! the isotope filtering with select is exactly what I am looking for but my knowledge of javascript is limited so if I have to tweek it too much I might have to go the HTML route. My question is on the isotope filter with select.- -the example show one dropdrop down tab. If I create 5 dropdown tabs will the javascript change?

Comment: You have made a question and got answered. Now you made another question as you are not asking for 1 as your example also shows but you are asking for combination filters. You need to limit to ask and get the answer, if you have more questions then you ask them as a separate. Anyway this is a combo filter http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/GFbAs But since you have not much knowledge of js, I would suggest bootstrap dropdown http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns. Anyway if you accept my answer as it does answer your first question, it would be nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have a same issue, I want filtration with 5 dropdown. Trying to achive target. I took filter string from combination of all selected values of dropdown and set it as filer to isotope. Like, my container has 4-5 diifferent element like body type,Meal type,Protein,DIETARY-PERFRENCE etc. 
but when I am selecting from dropdown all values like from body type:varbs, from Meal type : smoothy,from Protein:Pork then wont filter items because some records has data-filter separate like smoothy or pork etc because of that when my filter is .carbs.smoothey then it won't display any record it hides all records :( becuase I dont have records with all property. but records have separate property, then why it display such records which has at least single property from selected drop down value.

so implemented following code, and for now to continued my task. If anyone know how to solve this issue please let me know

I did following code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){    
    var $container = jQuery("#content");

    $container.isotope({
        filter: "*",
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: "linear",
            queue: false,
        },
        itemSelector: ".span4",
        layoutMode: "fitRows"
    });

    $("#bodytype-1").change(function(){
        $( "#bodytype-1 option:selected" ).each(function() {    
            selector1 = $(this).attr("data-filter");             
            document.getElementById("bodytype-1").setAttribute("data-active",selector1);   
            reorder(1);
            return false;
        });
    }); 

    $("#bodytype-2").change(function(){
        $( "#bodytype-2 option:selected" ).each(function() {
            selector2 = $(this).attr("data-filter");           
            document.getElementById("bodytype-2").setAttribute("data-active",  selector2);   
            reorder(2);
            return false;   
        });
    });

    $("#bodytype-3").change(function(){
        $( "#bodytype-3 option:selected" ).each(function() {
            selector3 = $(this).attr("data-filter");           
            document.getElementById("bodytype-3").setAttribute("data-active", selector3);   
            reorder(3);
            return false;
        });
    });

    $("#bodytype-4").change(function(){
        $( "#bodytype-4 option:selected" ).each(function() {
            selector4 = $(this).attr("data-filter");           
            document.getElementById("bodytype-4").setAttribute("data-active", selector4);   
            reorder(4);
            return false;   
        });
    });

    function reorder( k ){
        var bodytype = $("#bodytype-"+k).attr("data-active");
        if (typeof bodytype === "undefined") {
             bodytype = "";
        }
        var filterString = bodytype;      
        if(filterString=="*"){
            filterString = "*"; 
        }
        $container.isotope({
            filter: filterString,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: "linear",
                queue: false,
            },
            itemSelector: ".span4",
            layoutMode: "fitRows"
        });
    }
});
```